# Please I'm having a problem with my Laravel script when I try to login the admin page it shows Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[this is how it displays the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ollPM.jpg)

I tried changing the PHP version to 7.3 still not working
[This the line of code that's giving that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdT76.jpg)

Comment: Your PHP version has nothing to do with it. The error is clear on what is says. `$appitem->stage->sresource` just isn't an array, but `null`.

Answer (score 1):

As the error is saying the problem comes from the fact that you try to use a null value as an array, from what I see this code is problematic:

```
$appitem->stage->sresource['stage_id']
```

Could be a typo maybe that you have `sresource` instead of `resource` and that is the reason why `$appitem->stage->sresource` is null?

Comment: I'm thinking it's an old PHP version